# Error in inserting python variable in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am working on a raspberry pi project, in which I'm fetching data from plc and storing it into mysql database.

Here is my code:

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial
import mysql.connector


instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyAMA0',3,mode='rtu')
instrument.serial.baudrate=115200
instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout = 0.05


con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='raspberry',host='localhost',
                              database='Fujiplc')

cursor = con.cursor()

try:
    reg_value=instrument.read_register(102)
    print reg_value
    cursor.execute("insert into Register_Values values(%s)",(reg_value))
    print ('One row inserted successfully.')
except IOError:
    print("Failed to read from PLC.")


print (cursor.rowcount)

con.commit()

cursor.close()

con.close()
```

After running this code, I get next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/rpi_to_plc_read.py", line 22, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into Register_Values values(%d)",(reg_value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 477, in execute
    stmt = operation % self._process_params(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 355, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

I have gone through so many solutions but problem couldn't solve.
Please help me.

Comment: 152 is data that program fetched from plc.

Comment: i have also tried %d in place of %s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think should be.

```
cursor.execute("insert into Register_Values values(%s)",(reg_value))
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty common error in python.

`(reg_value)` is not a tuple
`(reg_value,)` is a tuple